# hyphen-delimited to CamelCase and CamelCase to hyphen-delimited

Tags: php, string

Does anyone know the **fastest** way to do conversion in each direction?

Currently I'm using this for hyphen-to-CamelCase:

```
$Hstring = 'hello-world';
$CCstring = implode('', array_map('ucwords', explode('-', $Hstring)));
```

Comment: Are you doing this so often in your script that speed really matters? (Like tens of thousands of times)

Comment: Not so often (70-80 times), but I would like the optimum solution :)

Comment: the optimum solution is to pre-compute the solution so there is no longer a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just published the package, which does exactly that: https://github.com/sebastiansulinski/string-converter

You can also pull it with the packagist.

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok but srsly u have to stop writing code like those symfony hipsters. That whole thing could be just one class with a few functions

Comment: There is a good reason behind building packages this way and following design patterns.

Answer (score 3):

```
$subject = 'abc-def-xyz';
$results = preg_replace_callback ('/-(.)/', create_function('$matches','return strtoupper($matches[1]);'), $subject);

var_dump($results);
```

and

```
$subject = 'abcDefXyz';
$results = preg_replace_callback ('/([A-Z])/', create_function('$matches','return \'-\' . strtolower($matches[1]);'), $subject);

var_dump($results);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to know whether it's faster, you'll need to profile it to determine that

Comment: second produces "-camel-case" from "CamelCase". also "-string-x-m-l" from "StringXML". I suggest `/.+([A-Z]+)/` instead. upvote when fixed